# Store Multiple values on a single Key in arduino

Tags: c, arduino, key-value, arduino-uno

Is there any library or function in **Arduino** which can store multiple values on a single key??

i.e. Suppose i have 4 sensor modules and each sensor module reported 3 readings like below

```
    key:  value1 value2 value3

sensor1:  data1  data2  data3
sensor2:  data1  data2  data3
sensor3:  data1  data2  data3
```

I had checked HashMap library but thats not worked in my case because i need to use sensor's data according to their key value. Also i had used 2D array logic, But finding Better solution. Stuck here, so please help me if someone have solution regarding it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a 2D array, where the first index is the key and second index(es) are values?

Comment: @SouravGhosh I had already used 2D array for temporary solution, But finding better solution

Comment: I do not totally understand your question however it would seem that you could just store the data as a struct into the hash map using the sensor name as the key. Then retrieve the data using the sensor name and use an enumeration type to indicate which of the struct fields to access and use.

Comment: @Richard Chambers: on HashMap link there is only two functions.1>hashMap.getIndexOf(" ")and 2> hashMap.getValueOf(" "), But there is no function which can give values from given index.

Comment: You can wrap the `hashMap.getValueOf('')` with another function `GetSensorValue ("", index)` or since this appears to be C++ if you are using http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/HashMap then can you just create a new class that contains HashMap and provide the necessary methods?

Comment: @Richard Chambers: I am using http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/HashMap , so need to define new method according to my requirement. I will try that and update soon.